# maya change to work in pixels

Tags: maya

When working in maya, the units are default on centimeters. I know that you can change it to millimeters, but is there a way to change it to work in pixels? Like for example let's say I wanted to make an object 20 pixels wide

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the forum for non-programming related Maya questions, but here's an answer anyway.

The short answer is no, there's no way to use pixels as a modeling unit in Maya. 3D objects in Maya (or any 3D software for that matter) are basically resolution-independent. It's like Adobe Illustrator in the sense that you can zoom further and further on an object, and it will still be drawn with the same fidelity. That's because you're dealing with theoretical points in 3D space. The line drawn between them could be divided up into infinitely smaller segments.

Pixels are important when you render, and if you wanted an *image* of an object to be 20 pixels wide, then you would have to set your render settings to be a certain size and then frame the object in the camera so that it would be 20 pixels wide. That would probably not be the way I would go about it, but it's possible. Again, because it's basically resolution independent, you could make your object as big or small as you wanted in relation to the render resolution.